# angularjs, creating a filter for a directive

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to create a `filter` in angular that can have an effect on the way the data bound to a directive can be output, similar to how `json` filter can be applied to an expression.

I am having a lot of trouble with this though, as it seems defining a filter isn't enough to work on anything but inline expressions. I'm absolutely certain I've seen it done before, though.

## Question

Is it possible to **create** a filter that works inline with a directive? Like this?

```
<div ng-directive="Model.Target | filterName"></div>
```

## Update

`ng-model` was only an example. I'm not looking for an existing filter, I'm not looking for how to apply filters, I'm not looking for `ng-repeat`. I *specifically* want to create a *new* filter that can work with a directive.

## Update 2

Trying to do this a bit more, I researched the `angular` source code ([line 154 of filters.js)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c94329a891a1c082567c490ccf58ba8592b464ad/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L154) and attempted to emulate the code there, but I am met with strange behavior. Using this code;

```
.filter('sample', function () {
    return function (obj) {
        console.log("typoef: ", typeof obj);
    }
});
```

I attempt to bind it to a directive;

```
<div data-ng-custom-directive="Model.Tags | sample"></div>
```

I get the error ...

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Custom directive isn't really anything special, it just takes the object given and does some parsing to it before shipping it off to the `$scope.Model.Tags` object.

Someone mentioned that you cannot put a filter on `ng-model`, and this is confusing to me. Is it just `ng-model`, or is it any directive *other* than `ng-repeat` that you cannot apply a directive to? The way I understand it, there are simply no filters *written* that work against `ng-model`, and while I am not trying to do that exactly, the concept is not too dissimilar.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer it. Can you not put a filter on any directive, or just ng-model?

Comment: Yes you can put it, eg with `ng-repeat` expression which is evaluated obviously by ng-repeat directive , it makes no sense to put it on ngModel though as per your example

Comment: Alright. `ng-model` was just an example. Do you know of any examples of filters that work on other directives? I'm wanting to see how they are made so I can make a filter for a different directive.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I essentially want to use some filters to change the behavior of a directive as needed. The things I need to set, they are getting hard to manage as individual directives, and so I thought filters might be a good thing to try for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is not with the filter but what type of binding you use for your directive's variable (attribute). You need to use `'='`. Example:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-init="test = [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div dir-a="test | limitTo:3"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
.directive('dirA', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            dirA: '=' // this is important, '@' would not work
        },
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            console.log('$scope.dirA = ', $scope.dirA);
        }
    };
});
```

prints to console `"$scope.dirA = " Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]`

Comment: oh my god, this makes so much more sense now. I've not accomplished what I want yet, but it isn't giving me the same stupid errors anymore! Thank you so much.

Comment: To elaborate more of what I am trying to do ...I have a third party library that has many angular directives, but there are a lot of options to set. Making custom directives for them _does work_, but it is starting to look really obtuse and irritating. I am new to angular, and want to learn, so I thought that trying to do the options as filters would be a good next step. Mainly because a lot of the options are true/false flags, not things that need a value passed.